# BigQuery is scanning the entire destination table when using a DBT incremental table

Tags: google-bigquery, dbt

**What's the problem?**

BigQuery is scanning the entire table being incrementally altered in the merge statement when I run incremental updates.

For big tables (40GB plus), this is a pretty decent cost and exactly the thing I'm trying to avoid with incremental updates.

Just to be clear I am avoiding the cost of querying the entire raw table, but I'm not avoiding the cost of querying the entire dbt table.

Showing a smaller table as an example here, you can see the new results are a handful of KBs, but the merge statement hits the entire table (73MB).

[image]

Is this a bug/something wrong with my setup/something un-avoidable?

**Details**

I'm running a decent number of incremental models on BigQuery. They all look (in the basic form) something like this:

The example below is an example running on Google ads data, but they're not too different. They run on a partitioned table in BigQuery, munge some data and return

```sql
{{
    config(
        materialized="incremental",
        partition_by={"field": "pt", "data_type": "timestamp", "granularity": "day"},
        incremental_strategy="insert_overwrite",
    )
}}

with
    new_api_lookup as (
        select
            campaign_id as campaign_id,
            ad_group_id as adgroup_id,
            _partitiontime as pt,
            sum(metrics_clicks) as total_clicks,
            sum(metrics_impressions) as total_impressions,
            sum(metrics_conversions_value) as conversion_value
        from `{{ var("ad_bq_export")["new"]["t_adGroupStats"] }}`
        where
            date(_partitiontime) > date('{{ var("bq_ad_api_migrate_date") }}')
            {% if is_incremental() %}

            -- When rerun this will delete the last days data.
            and _partitiontime >= _dbt_max_partition
            {% endif %}
        group by campaign_id, adgroup_id, pt
    )
    {% if var("bq_ads_old_api") %}
    ,
    old_api_lookup as (
        select
            campaignid as campaign_id,
            adgroupid as adgroup_id,
            _partitiontime as pt,
            sum(clicks) as total_clicks,
            sum(impressions) as total_impressions,
            sum(conversionvalue) as conversion_value
        from `{{ var("ad_bq_export")["old"]["t_adGroupStats"] }}`
        where
            date(_partitiontime) <= date('{{ var("bq_ad_api_migrate_date") }}')
            {% if is_incremental() %}

            -- When rerun this will delete the last days data.
            and _partitiontime >= _dbt_max_partition
            {% endif %}
        group by campaign_id, adgroup_id, pt
    )
    {% endif %}
select *
from
    (
        select *
        from new_api_lookup
        {% if var("bq_ads_old_api") %}
        union all
        select *
        from old_api_lookup
        {% endif %}
    )
```

This generates into a DBT model of which the problematic part is:

```
   -- 3. run the merge statement
      

    merge into `my-project`.`table`.`_ads_adGroup_stats` as DBT_INTERNAL_DEST
        using (
        select
        * from `my-project`.`table`.`_ads_adGroup_stats__dbt_tmp`
      ) as DBT_INTERNAL_SOURCE
        on FALSE

    when not matched by source
         and timestamp(timestamp_trunc(DBT_INTERNAL_DEST.pt, day)) in unnest(dbt_partitions_for_replacement) 
        then delete

    when not matched then insert
        (`campaign_id`, `adgroup_id`, `pt`, `total_clicks`, `total_impressions`, `conversion_value`)
    values
        (`campaign_id`, `adgroup_id`, `pt`, `total_clicks`, `total_impressions`, `conversion_value`)
```

This runs on a 1.6 million row table, updates ~ 2k rows but scans the entire table doing it. _dbt_max_partition does contain the date expected so it should only be replacing one partition and according to the blog post on this topic, this shouldn't be happening unless I've misread it.

https://discourse.getdbt.com/t/bigquery-dbt-incremental-changes/982

What am I missing?

Comment: You missed the `where` condition :  `merge into .... Where {partition column}  > {date}
        on FALSE` This where condition must be know before execution. Thus please create a list beforhand in dbt.

Comment: For the list are you talking about settings partitions_to_replace statically?

The DBT blog post suggests you can do it dynamically as I've shown above and `the cost of an incremental run decreases from a full scan of the existing table to a metadata query—getting the max of the partition column—and a full scan of only the partitions with new data.`

In case it's helpful context, DBT is generating:

`declare dbt_partitions_for_replacement array<timestamp>;`

I just only put in the merge statement.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out this is a bug with the older versions of DBT Bigquery. Upgrading to 1.5 solved this for me.

https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-bigquery/issues/536